# Pandas table names

Tags: python, pandas

I created a small dataframe in pandas that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'weather':[16,22,32,8,2]})
df
```

in the output is gives me a table:

```
    weather
0   16
1   22
2   32
3   8
4   2
```

I cant find a proper explanation on how to change this table so that instead of 0,1,2,3,4 I can input words(for example: Monday, Tuesday etc)

Comment: The first column represents the indexes of your rows. You have to add a new column with words (Monday, Thuesday,etc...)

Answer (score 1):

This is so called `index`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'weather':[16,22,32,8,2]},index=['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri'])
df
Out[36]: 
     weather
Mon       16
Tue       22
Wed       32
Thu        8
Fri        2
```

Comment: I think OP need `rename`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, if your index are not in order and you want to map them according to the count, you can do:

```
import calendar
d = {i:e for i,e in enumerate(list(calendar.day_name))}

df.index=df.index.map(d)
print(df)

           weather
Monday          16
Tuesday         22
Wednesday       32
Thursday         8
Friday           2
```